# PySide / QT Align text in vertical center for QPushButton

Tags: python, css, qt, fonts, pyside2

How can I vertically align the text in a large font QPushButton? For example this Python code creates a button where the text is not vertically aligned. I have tried everything I can think of to solve it but I can't get it working.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+") # "a" or "A"
button.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px")

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(button)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()'
```

Here is what the code above creates:

[image] [image] [image]

Note that I am running this code in Maya but it should be the same problem in an QT environment I think.

Comment: "the text is not vertically aligned" That's not correct. The *plus sign* is not visually aligned, but that's because: 1. the plus symbol normally has the height of a lower case letter; 2. the ascent of fonts doesn't normally match the actual visible height of uppercase fonts, so even an uppercase letter may not be perfectly centered vertically. If you want a plus symbol perfectly centered on the button, you should use an icon.

Comment: I see, that helps a lot thanks. That said, whether it is a + or any lowercase letter you have the same problem. I would love a solution that doesn't require me creating an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example this Python code creates a button where the text is not vertically aligned.

In reality, the text *is* vertically aligned: you are not considering how text is normally rendered.

### Brief sum of vertical font elements

When dealing with text drawing, the *font metrics* (see [typeface anatomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_anatomy)) should always be considered. Vertically speaking, a typeface always has a fundamental *height*, and its drawing is always based on the *base line*.

Consider the following image, which renders the text `xgdÖ_+`:

[image: Vertical aspects of a font]

The ["baseline"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) is the vertical reference position from which every character is being drawn; you can consider it like the lines of a notebook: it's where you normally place the bottom part of the circle of "o", or the dot of a question mark, and the bottom of letters such as "g" are normally drawn *underneath* that line.

Qt always uses the [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) of a given font, and it uses font metrics functions in order to properly display text; those functions always have some reference to the base line above.

From the base line, then, we can get the following relative distances:

- [`descent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#descent): which is the distance to the lowest point of the characters (the [*descender*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender));
- [`xHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#xHeight): the distance to the height of a lower case character that has no [*ascender*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)), which normally is the height of the letter `x` (see [x-height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height));
- [`capHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#capHeight): the height of a standard upper case letter (see [cap height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height));
- [`ascent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#ascent): the maximum upper extent of a font above the *x-height*, normally (but not always) allowing further space for letters such "d", diacritic marks for upper case letters, or fancy decorations;

Finally, the whole font [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#height) is the sum of the ascent and descent. From there, you can get the "center" (often coinciding but not to be confused with the [*median* or *mean line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_line)), which is where a `Qt.AlignVCenter` aligned text would normally have as its virtual middle line when showing vertically centered text in Qt.

Simply put (as more complex text layouts may complicate things), when Qt draws some text, it uses the font metrics `height()` as a reference, and then aligns the text on the computed distances considering the overall height and/or the ascent and descent of the metrics. Once the proper base line has been found, the text is finally drawn based on it.

### Vertical alignment is *wrong* (or not?)

When Qt aligns some text, it always considers the metrics of the font, which can be misleading. Consider the case above, and imagine that you wanted to use the underscore character (`_`) for your button, which clearly is placed way below the base line.

The result would be something like this:

[image: Button using underscore character as text]

This is clearly not "vertically aligned". It seems wrong, but is it?

As you can see from the image above, the "+" symbol is not vertically aligned to the center in the font I'm using. But, even if it was, would it be valid?

For instance, consider a button with "x" as its text, but using that letter as its *mnemonic* shortcut, which is normally underlined. Even assuming that you can center the x, would it be properly aligned when underlined?

Some styles even show the underlined mnemonic only upon user interaction (usually by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>): should the text be vertically translated in that case?

### Possible implementation

Now, it's clear that considering the overall vertical alignment *including* the mnemonic is not a valid choice.

But there is still a possibility, using [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) functions and some ingenuity.

QPushButton draws its contents using a relatively simple `paintEvent()` override:

```cpp
void QPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(
&option);
    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, 
option);
}
```

This can be ported in Python with the following:

```py
class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QStylePainter(self)
        option = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        p.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option)
```

Since `p.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option)` will use the [`option.text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionbutton.html#text-var), we can draw a no-text button with the following:

```py
class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QStylePainter(self)
        option = QStyleOptionButton()
        option.text = ''
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        p.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option)
```

Now comes the problem: how to draw the text.

While we could simply use QPainter functions such as [`drawText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText), this won't be appropriate, as we should consider style aspects that use custom drawing: for instance, disabled buttons, or style sheets.

A more appropriate approach should consider the *offset* between the center of the font metrics and the *visual center* of the character(s) we want to draw.

[QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) allows us to add some text to a vector path and get its visual center based on its contents. So, we can use [`addText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#addText) and subtract the difference of its center from the center of the font metrics `height()`.

Here is the final result:

```py
class CenterTextButton(QPushButton):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.text().strip():
            super().paintEvent(event)
            return

        qp = QStylePainter(self)

        # draw the button without text
        opt = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        text = opt.text
        opt.text = ''
        qp.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt)

        fm = self.fontMetrics()

        # ignore mnemonics temporarily
        tempText = text.replace('&', '')
        if '&&' in text:
            # consider *escaped* & characters
            tempText += '&'

        p = QPainterPath()
        p.addText(0, 0, self.font(), tempText)

        # the relative center of the font metrics height
        fontCenter = fm.ascent() - fm.height() / 2
        # the relative center of the actual text
        textCenter = p.boundingRect().center().y()
        # here comes the magic...
        qp.translate(0, -(fontCenter + textCenter))

        # restore the original text and draw it as a real button text
        opt.text = text
        qp.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButtonLabel, opt)
```

### Further notes

The above implementation is not perfect. Most importantly:

- some styles draw a "focus outline", which normally is a dashed line around the text, and in that case a small dashed rectangle may be drawn at the center of the button; this can be completely disabled by doing `opt.state &= ~QStyle.State_HasFocus` before `qp.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt)`, but may have effects in case stylesheets are being used;
- as said, mnemonics that show underlined characters may result in unexpected behavior;
- character display is not regular: the apparent visual center of a complex shape as that of one or more characters is not always the center of its *bounding rectangle*;
- fonts are **not** reliable: while most common fonts are well designed, there are plenty of faulty fonts that are inconsistent to some extent (and depending on the given size); even fonts have *bugs*;
- the above obviously does *not* consider buttons with icons;

Finally, for simple symbols like in this case, using an icon is almost always the better choice.

Luckily, Qt also has SVG file support for icons, and it also provides a [QIconEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiconengine.html) API that allows further customization.

Answer (score 0):

[musicamante's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834580/pyside-qt-align-text-in-vertical-center-for-qpushbutton?noredirect=1#comment137218087_77834580) is spot on: this is not being caused because of a vertical align issue, it is being caused because the lowercase letter is smaller than the uppercase letter (and the vertical align happens according to the uppercase letter's size).

Adding some padding is an easy way to fix the issue visually:

```
button.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px; padding-bottom: 10px")
```

[image]

Comment: More robust fix: `button.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px; text-align: center")`.

Comment: That doesn't work hey @ekhumoro

Comment: Works perfectly on Linux. Actually, for me, there's no difference between `text-align: center` and `padding: 0px` (i.e. the value doesn't matter).

Comment: @Frank Sorry but this is completely inappropriate: 1. the padding is completely arbitrary and only based on your current font (people using a different font displaying the "+" with a different vertical position will probably see much different results); 2. the padding is clearly based on unreliable visual attempts. In fact, the distance between the margins of the button and the actual symbol are completely inconsistent in your screenshot: even ignoring anti-aliasing, the distance between the top of the symbol and the button edge is 57 pixels, while the distance on the bottom is only 43 pixels.

Comment: @ekhumoro That may be caused by the fact that your default font actually places the plus symbol exactly in the midline (`(ascent + descent) / 2`); also, if you use `padding: <value>` (instead of a more specific and indirectly exclusive `padding-bottom: <value>`), the vertical alignment would be always centered anyway.

Comment: @musicamante Actually, when I try it again today, ***none*** of those stylesheet rules behave in the way they did yesterday, and I can't now work out what I was doing differently. However, the point is moot, since this was never going to provide a completely reliable solution anyway.

Comment: @musicamante to be fair I don't think my solution is completely inappropriate, it solves the problem for me and therefore might solve it for others. Although I'm sure you are correct on the technical side of things and I appreciate your feedback a lot.

Comment: @Frank I understand that this may be fine enough for you, but in reality it solves the problem only for your current font, and it does it *imprecisely* and *unreliably*: as said, it's not really centered, as it can be clearly seen with the naked eye; while making the button taller would obviously reduce the effect, ad this height a 43/57 difference means that the top space is shorter by 1/4, and the bottom taller than 1/3 (making the button taller will obviously reduce the effect). With a different font I even get 37/54, meaning that the top is taller by *half* than the bottom.

Comment: @Frank Moreover, this can also have issues with different combinations of font scaling and HighDPI systems. As a rule of thumb, distances such as margins and paddings should never be chosen using the font as reference (unless font metrics are **dynamically** taken into account, but even that isn't 100% reliable), adjustments in text alignment can never use arbitrary values (especially in widgets), and, most importantly, such adjustments can never rely on visual perception of "one" font : what you see on your computer is almost *never* what everybody else will see on theirs.